# Resizing Julia Plot Pane in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, julia, plots.jl

I have been using Julia in VSCode for some time now, and plotting using Plots.jl and the gr() backend. At some point, the output to the plot pane became zoomed in, outputting something like this:

[image: Plot Pane]

I tried the following:

```
using Plots
gr(size = (400, 400))
```

with various size arguments. This changes the size of the plot within the plot pane, but not the size of the image itself. How can I resize the image?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that will help, but it happen in my VSCode after `Pkg.update()` and after restarting VSCode it just fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If you switch to using Plotly or PlotlyJS (I use them directly, but they can also be used as backends to Plots.jl) then the plot resizes dynamically as you change the size of the plot pane.